# How can I use a private key in an ssh client for only one host?

Tags: ssh

I'm using Ubuntu. How can I use a private key in an ssh client for only one host? The private key is used for all hosts, every time I connect to any server, the private key authentication is used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create or edit your SSH configuration file at `~/.ssh/config`.

For all the details, check `man ssh_config`. But basically, it consists of several entries like this:

```
Host example
    Hostname example.com
    User quber
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_idfile
```

A `Host` line introduces each host, and the following lines are indented. The name on the Host line is a nickname (you will type `ssh example` instead of `ssh quber@example.com`.) If you don't want to use a nickname, you can use the full hostname:

```
Host example.com
    User quber
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_idfile
```

Now ssh will automatically use the specified username and private key for this host, and only this host.

If you don't want the private key to be used for other hosts, make sure it is not named `id_dsa`, `id_rsa`, or the other files which are used by default for all hosts (the whole list is in `man ssh`). Give it a unique name, perhaps pertaining to the host it's for.

Comment: i created this config, but does't work
Host vds <public_ip>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    User root
but when i connect to another server in local network 
ssh 192.168.1.4
Enter passphrase for key '/home/<User>/.ssh/id_rsa':

Comment: @quber See `man 5 ssh_config` where it describes `IdentityFile`. `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is used *by default* (i.e. also for the other server in your case). Use a non-default name for the key you don't want to be used automatically. Then specify the renamed key in the config file like the answer says. I think the answer deliberately named the example key `my_idfile`, *not* `id_rsa`.

Comment: Additionally,  the Host line can have multiple entries appended, space separated.